# Putting search icon in search input, then centering both in page

Tags: html, css

I've managed to get the search icon IN the input field, and can center the input field with margin: 0 auto and displaying it to block (but this keeps from the icon being in the field and keeps it at the right of the page, since it's on block - yet it's the only way I've managed to center it).  New to HTML/CSS, so is there a proper way to do this? Looking to learn.

Currently have this code:

```css
@import url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
.search {
  position: relative;
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.search input {
  width: 500px;
  height: 32px;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.search input {
  text-indent: 32px;
}

.search .fa-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
  <input placeholder="Search term" id="search" class="keyword">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The input is an inline element, consider centering the the wrapper which is a div (block element) on where you can use `margin:auto`. You may also use max-width to make it responsive on small screen:

```css
@import url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");


.search {
  position: relative;
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 16px;
  max-width: 500px;
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.search input {
  width:100%;
  height: 32px;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.search input {
  text-indent: 32px;
}

.search .fa-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
  <input placeholder="Search term" id="search" class="keyword">
</div>
```

Comment: I was thinking you had to do something like this. Thank you for explaining.